# How to do a Real time sound headroom with bar charts in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, signal-processing, pyaudio

I am trying to do a simple sound headroom using a bar chart and Pyaudio. After several attemps I realize that the problem is related with the while loop. This makes me think.. how to get a value from the loop? The main problem is that the bar chart overlaps making the code slower throuh the time. Is it possible to do it like this?

This is the image of the chart now:
[image]

and want something similar to this:

[image]

The principal idea is to have this chart in movement with the levels.

And this is the code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pyaudio as pa 
import struct 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fps =   516

CHUNK = fps * 2
FORMAT = pa.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100 

p = pa.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = CHANNELS,
    rate = RATE,
    input=True,
    output=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_ylim(-80,40)
fig.show()

while True:
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)

    dataInt = np.array(struct.unpack(str(CHUNK) + 'h', data))
    
    datadBFs = 20*np.log10(np.abs(np.sum(dataInt)/len(dataInt))/32768)
    ax.bar("bar1", datadBFs, align='center', alpha=0.5)
    
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Any Idea?
Thanks a lot and I hope someone could help me!

Comment: Your `while` expression is always `True` which means your `while` loop will keep running the code inside it. Is that what you want?

Comment: @medium-dimensional I understand the while loop is to visualize the audio in Realtime, I would like to plot the bar chart and update every certain time (or samples) without overlap of the previous bar (or data). Do you think is possible?

Comment: Yes, I think it's possible. You can pause the while loop execution for few seconds using `time.sleep` function.